# File Operations with Multiple Processes

Tags: c, file-io, process, exec

Actually I am trying to access a file in two different process first of which is parent process and  of which is child process. They are able to access the file and read its contents. My expectation is that the process continue to read the file from the point in which another one remains. For example, parent process reads first two lines. After that, child process starts to read the lines 5th 6th 7th and 8th. However, they do not run like my expectation.

exec.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(void){

    pid_t pidValue = fork();


    if( pidValue == -1 ){
        printf("Creating new process failed\n");
    }

    else if( pidValue == 0 ){

        printf("Child Process ID = %d\n", getpid());
        printf("Parent Process ID = %d\n", getppid());
        execlp("./test", "U", "N", "I", "X", (char*)NULL);
        sleep(5);
    }

    else{
        printf("This is parent process : \n");
        printf("\tChild Process ID = %d\n", pidValue);
        printf("\tParent Process ID = %d\n", getpid());

        FILE *fptr = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
        int x = 0;
        char *name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);
        int age;
        while( x < 4 ){
            fscanf(fptr, "%s %d", name, &age);
            printf("%s %d\n", name, age);
            ++x;
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){

    int x = 0;

    while( x < argc ){
        printf("%s", argv[x++]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    FILE *fptr = fopen("sample.txt", "r");

    int i = 0;
    int age;
    char *name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);

    while( i < 4 ){
        fscanf(fptr, "%s %d", name, &age);
        printf("%s %d\n", name, age);
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

sample.txt :

```
A 65
B 66
C 67
D 68
E 69
F 70
G 71
H 72
```

How can I make the processes follow the point which they remain in ?

Comment: Each process has its own file pointer.

Answer (score 0):

File pointer is not like any other pointer. So you can not increment a file pointer to pointing at a particular line in a file. Every time you use a `gets()` call it read the line where it is pointing to. So you can not do so in two different process that you are trying at the moment. But you can achieve it with multithreads by sharing a global file pointer. But file read method must by synchronize else multiple thread might ended up reading the same line from the file.

Also when you use a `fork()` call it copies all the data, memory address to its child process which become local to that process. Hence file pointer you are referring to your main process and file pointer in your child process are different. Hence manipulation of file pointer in one process is never going to impact the file pointer in the other process.